# Update email after Apple Firebase Auth

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-authentication, apple-sign-in

A problem I have is when a user login with Apple at first, and then he updates the Email, so it causes the refresh token to expire.
According to the [document](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-sessions) here, refresh token will expire when email address has been updated.

I tried to use reauthenticate function as below, but the credential must be created first as parameters. In order to get the credential, the user must re-login Apple again in order to get a new nonce, is there any way to avoid the prompt of the apple login window again, and also to get the credential smoothly?

```
let credential = OAuthProvider.credential(withProviderID: "apple.com",
                             idToken: idToken,
                             rawNonce: nonce)

let user = Auth.auth().currentUser

user?.reauthenticate(with: credential) { error in
  if let error = error {
    // An error happened.
  } else {
    // User re-authenticated.
  }
}
```

I have seen an answer from [here](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues/4434) that I can get a new credential as below, but the key here is nil.

```
(error! As NSError) .userInfo [AuthErrorUserInfoUpdatedCredentialKey])
```